# What happens when a thread is constructed, and how is the thread executed

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm completely new to multithreading and have a little trouble understanding how multithreading actually works.

Let's consider the following example of code. The program simply takes file names as input and counts the number of lowercase letters in them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctype.h>

class LowercaseCounter{
public:
    LowercaseCounter() :
        total_count(0)
    {}
    void count_lowercase_letters(const std::string& filename)
    {
        int count = 0;
        std::ifstream fin(filename);
        char a;
        while (fin >> a)
        {
            if (islower(a))
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
                ++total_count;
            }
        }
    }
    void print_num() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
        std::cout << total_count << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int total_count;
    mutable std::mutex m;
};
int main(){
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> threads;
    LowercaseCounter counter;
    std::string line;
    while (std::cin >> line)
    {
        if (line == "exit")
            break;
        else if (line == "print")
            counter.print_num(); //I think that this should print 0 every time it's called.
        else
            threads.emplace_back(new std::thread(&LowercaseCounter::count_lowercase_letters, counter, line));
    }
    for (auto& thread : threads)
        thread->join();
}
```

Firstly I though that the output of `counter.print_num()` will print 0 as far as the threads are not 'joined' yet to execute the functions. However, It turns out that the program works correctly and the output of `counter.print_num()` is not 0. So I asked myself the following questions.

What actually happens when a thread is constructed?

If the program above works fine, then thread must be executed when is created, then what does `std::thread::join` method do?

If the thread is executed at the time of creation, then what's the point of using multithreading in this example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you think a thread is more like a coroutine. Threads **start** executing at creation and `join()` waits until the thread **ends**. Beyond that, it runs in parallel to all other threads, possibly on a different CPU core.

Comment: @Frank If thread has a specified **start** time(at the construction), then I suppose that it should have a specified **end** time. What do you mean when you say `join()` waits until thread ends?

Comment: The thread simply ends once it's entrypoint function returns, the same way a program ends when it reaches the end of `main()`.

Comment: @Frank So what would happen if I didn't call `join()` method for each one of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that the program can only be running one thread at a time, and that it needs to interrupt whatever it's doing in order to execute the code of the thread. That's not the case.

You can think of a thread as a completely separate program that happens to share memory and resources with the program that created it. The function you pass as an argument is that program's 'main()` for every intent and purpose. In Linux, threads are *literally* separate processes, but as far as C++ is concerned, that's just an implementation detail.

So, in a modern operating system with preemptive multitasking, much like multiple programs can run at the same time, threads *can* also run at the same time. Note that I say *can*, it's up to the compiler and OS to decide when to give CPU time to each thread.

> then what does std::thread::join method do?

It just waits until the thread is done.

> So what would happen if I didn't call join() method for each one of threads

It would crash upon reaching the end of `main()` because attempting to exit the program without joining a non-detached thread is considered an error.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, in c++ the thread is executed when it is created all `std::thread::join` does is wait for the thread to finish execution.

In your code all the threads will start executing simultaneously in the loop and then the main thread will wait for each thread to finish execution in the next loop.

Comment: If thread has a specified start time(at the construction), then I suppose that it should have a specified end time. What do you mean when you say join() waits until thread ends?

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan Why should a thread have a specified end time? Suppose a thread calls a function that only exits when a stock goes above a specific value, the main thread should have no idea when the other thread will end execution. Now if the main thread wanted to execute code _only_  after that thread ends, you would call `join` on that thread and wait for it to end.

In summation, `join` basically pauses the main thread until the joined thread has finished executing.

Comment: You mean, pauses the thread that called join until the joined thread exits. Any thread can join another. The main thread has nothing to do with anything.